# Lifetime of MMAP value in linux

Tags: c, linux, mmap, beagleboneblack

Hi im using a beaglebone black running on debian, and i use `mmap` on */dev/mem* file to access GPIO registers.
I have a .c file that contains my mapping function:

```
//sample code

unsigned int *gpio_get_map(int gpio)

{

    unsigned int *gpio_addr = NULL;

    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
        gpio_addr = mmap(0, GPIO_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd, gpio_get_number(gpio));
        if(gpio_addr == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            printf("Unable to map GPIO : %s\n",strerror(errno));
            close(fd);
            return NULL;
        }
        close(fd);
        return gpio_addr;
}
```

Then i call this function in another .c file to get the value of `gpio_addr` and use it to manipulate the GPIOs, it works fine but i am not sure how long the `gpio_addr` will be valid.
Will the address given by the `gpio_addr` be always valid? Or should i call another `mmap` after some period of time? Thanks.

Comment: Note: `return -1;` is wrong in a function that claims to return a pointer-to-unsigned-int. Why not just return NULL on failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to renew the mapping. It will stay valid in the calling process until you explicitly unmap it (or the process ends).

Comment: does it mean that even if i use this .c as a python extension it will still be valid inside python code as long as the process doesn't end or i unmap it?